# Android: Ionic drawer icon overlaps with title

Tags: android, css, cordova, user-interface, ionic-framework

I am developing an android application in (ionic framework+cordova) which there is two screens
Login screen and dashboard screen ,when user is logged in it will redirect to dashboard.

Everything works fine but the problem is **`dashboard` title is overlapped with menu drawer icon until a refresh or a page change**.

Here is the  screen shot

[image]

Here is my dashboard.html

```
<ion-view title="Dashboard">

    <!--menu dashboard section-->
    <ion-content id="menu-dashboard-content">
        <!--panel section-->
        <div class="menu-panel">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-50 dashboard-blog" ng-click="navigateTo('app.newsFeed')">
                    <i class="icon-notebook"></i>
                   <p>Blogs</p>
                    <big>{{dashboard.blogs.total_count}}</big><br />
                    <span>{{dashboard.blogs.title}}</span><br />
                    {{dashboard.blogs.date}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-50 dashboard-calender" ng-click="navigateTo('app.calendarlist')">
                    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                    <p>Calender</p>
                    <big>{{dashboard.calander.total_count}}</big><br />
                    <span>{{dashboard.calander.title}}</span><br />
                    From {{dashboard.calander.from_date}} To
                    {{dashboard.calander.end_date}}
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-50 dashboard-todo" ng-click="navigateTo('app.todolist')">
                    <i class="icon-list"></i>
                    <p>To Do</p>
                    <big>{{dashboard.todo.total_count}}</big><br />
                    <span>{{dashboard.todo.title}}</span><br />
                    {{dashboard.todo.date}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-50 dashboard-note" ng-click="navigateTo('app.noteslist')">
                    <i class="icon-note"></i>
                    <p>Note</p>
                    <big>{{dashboard.notes.total_count}}</big><br />
                    <span>{{dashboard.notes.title}}</span><br />
                    {{dashboard.notes.date}} 
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-50 dashboard-notifications" ng-click="navigateTo('app.notificationlist')">
                    <i class="icon-bell"></i>
                    <p>Notifications</p>
                    <big>{{dashboard.notifications.total_count}}</big><br />
                    <span>{{dashboard.notifications.title}}</span><br />
                    {{dashboard.notifications.date}}
                </div>

                <div class="col-50 dashboard-support" ng-click="showToast('Updated soon')">
                    <i class="icon-support"></i>
                    <p>Support</p>
                    <big>{{dashboard.support.total_count}}</big><br />
                    <span>{{dashboard.support.title}}</span><br />
                    {{dashboard.support.date}}
                </div>


            </div>
        </div><!--end panel section-->

    </ion-content><!--Menu dashboard section-->
</ion-view>
```

**Controller file**

```
appControllers.controller('LoginCtrl',function($interval,$scope,$mdToast,$rootScope,$state){


$scope.doLogin=function(loginData){
   //api call
  //if success
   $state.go('app.menuDashboard');
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced  material-background-nav-bar">
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <a class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left" ng-click="toggleLeft()"></a>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <md-sidenav md-component-id="left" on-swipe-left="closeSideNav()" on-drag-left="closeSideNav()">
        <!--menu section-->
        <div class="material-background" id="toggle-menu-left-header">
            <!--menu header section-->
            <div class="menu-left-header" ng-click="navigateTo('app.profileview')">
                <img class="user-img" src="{{profile.profile_pic}}">
                <p>
                    <span class="title">{{profile.name}}</span>
                    <br/>
                    <span class="sub-title">{{profile.email}}</span>
                </p>
            </div><!--end menu header section-->
        </div> <!--menu content section-->
        <ion-content id="toggle-menu-left-content">

            <!--If device is android application will present below code.-->
            <!--It will disable animation to better performance on android.-->
            <!--list section-->
```

Comment: You may have to share CSS too i feel. Also in the HTML, i dont see notification drawer code.

Comment: Updated the drawer menu code